# How to run repeated tasks with handler

Tags: android, retrofit2, handler

I have a retrofit api that checks the status of the order.

For example, store_status is the variable that i am checking.

Default value of store_status is 0.

What i want to do is:

I want to check the value of this variable again and again for example in every 2 seconds till it returns value as 1. (The status is being updated from another app)

Also, i want a timer like if after checking the status for 3 mins again and again if it does not outputs the value as 1 the handler should stop and i want to update the value of store_status as 2 in database after 3 mins.

I have read post telling how to work with handler and how to run repeated tasks but i was not able to find to stop it automatically after like 3 mins and do something after that.

Can some one help with this task in both aspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Count Down Timer in Android which internally uses Handler, Runnable

[Check it out here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Comment: So u mean i implement my logic in onTick method() ??